# Not sure why I'm getting this attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

The assertEqual tests are from a module that just calls a function, runs some data through it, computes the result of that processed data, and compares it to my predicted answer.  For example, my predicted answer for `total_test` was 6.0.
When I run my code (below being the troubled part), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anon/Desktop/test.py", line 72, in <module>
    TransactionTest().run()
  File "C:/Users/anon/Desktop/test.py", line 68, in run
    self.total_test()
  File "C:/Users/anon/Desktop/test.py", line 60, in total_test
    assertEqual(self.__t1.total(), 6.0)
  File "C:/Users/anon/Desktop/test.py", line 18, in total
    return sum(map(lambda p: p.cost(), self.__purchases))
  File "C:/Users/anon/Desktop/test.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    return sum(map(lambda p: p.cost(), self.__purchases))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'cost'
```

All the line numbers should be shifted down a few lines to account for me copy and pasting it here very slightly modified.

Essentially, my total_test function is causing a crash when it's called.  Not sure why I'm getting an attribute error.

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, purchases, tax_rate):
        self.__purchases = purchases
        self.__tax_rate = tax_rate

    def total(self):
        return sum(map(lambda p: p.cost(), self.__purchases))

    def tax_rate(self):
        return self.__tax_rate

    def total_taxable(self):
        taxable_items = filter(lambda p: p.item().taxable(),self.__purchases) 
        return sum(map(lambda p: p.cost(), taxable_items))

    def grand_total(self):
        return self.total() + self.__tax_rate * self.total_taxable()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Total: " + self.__total + ";" + "Total_tax: " + self.__total_taxable * self.__tax_rate + ";" + "Grand Total: " + self.__grand_total
    def print_receipt(self):

        f = open("receipt.txt", "w")
        f.write("\n".join(map(lambda p:str(p),self.__purchases)))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("Total: $%.2f" % self.total())
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("Tax ( $%.2f @ %.2f %%): $%.2f" %(self.total_taxable(), self.__tax_rate * 100, self.__tax_rate * self.total_taxable()))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("Grand Total: $%.2f" % self.grand_total())
        f.close()
#problem 9-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TransactionTest:
    print('----------------------------')
    def __init__(self):
        t_list = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
        self.__t1 = Transaction(t_list, 0.05)
        #self.__d2 = Transaction(3.0, 0.06)

    def total_test(self):
        print('total_test-----------------------------------------')
        assertEqual(self.__t1.total(), 6.0)

    def tax_rate_test(self):
        print('tax_rate_test--------------------------------------')
        assertEqual(self.__t1.tax_rate(), 0.05)
        #assertEqual(self.__d2.tax_rate() = Transaction(0.06))

    def run(self):
        self.total_test()
        #self.tax_rate_test()
        #self.str_test()

TransactionTest().run()
```

Comment: Sorry, please ignore that bad doc-string for now.  That's let over from the copy and paste, and it's outdated!

Comment: I'll sort that out now. --Update: okay, it's gone.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your test code passes a list of three `float` instances, `[1.0,2.0,3.0]`, as the `purchases` argument to `Transaction`'s initializer. However, the other `Transaction` methods try to call various methods (e.g. `cost()` and `item()`) on the values from that list, and since `float` instances don't have the methods an exception is raised.

I suspect your `Transaction` code is intended to be run on a list of some other kind of object, where the appropriate methods are defined. You need to rewrite your tests to use the right kind of objects.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  I'll update later with the solution.